# Strong convexity definition based on subgradient

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient

Suppose that we have $f: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ is convex and satisfies
$$f(\textbf y) \geq f(\textbf x) + \nabla f(\textbf x)^\top(\textbf y - \textbf x) + \frac{\mu}{2} \| \textbf x - \textbf y \|^2
$$
$\forall \textbf x$ such that $\nabla f(\textbf x)$ exists and $\forall \textbf y$. Prove that
$$f(\textbf y) \geq f(\textbf x) + \textbf g_{\textbf x}^\top(\textbf y - \textbf x) + \frac{\mu}{2} \| \textbf x - \textbf y \|^2
$$
for all $\textbf x, \textbf g_{\textbf x} \in \partial f(\textbf x)$ and all $\textbf y$

**My attempt**: I'm trying to utilize the fact that convex function $f$ is differentiable *almost everywhere*, which means I can find $\textbf v$ with  arbitrary small norm that at $\textbf x + \textbf v$, $f$ is diferentiable. My calculation try to find a $\textbf v$ that has nice properties, but I'm stuck with term like $\nabla f(\textbf x + \textbf v)$.

I'm glad if anyone can tell if my direction is right, or if not, how can I tackle this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: The subdifferential of a convex function is the convex hull of the limiting gradients. I.e., for any point $y$, $\partial f(y) = \mathrm{conv}(\{z: \exists \{x_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}, x_k \in\mathrm{diff}(f), x_k\to y, \nabla f(x_k)\to z\})$.

Comment: @j.kookalinski So your point is that for any $\textbf x$ I can take a sequence $\textbf x_n$ and hence my problem is the direct corollary? Do you have the proof for the convex hull fact? Thanks

Comment: It's a little bit more work than that but yes, that's the idea. You can find this definition of the subdifferential in Clarke's book "Optimization and nonsmooth analysis". It is defined for all locally lipschitz functions (i.e., not just convex) but in the convex case it is equivalent to the "usual" subdifferential.

Comment: If a function is differentiable, then $\partial f(x) = \{\nabla f(x)\}$. So this has actually nothing to do with strong convexity.